# Fresh installed Debian 9 is bootin into black screen

Tags: linux, boot, drivers, debian

I just installed Debian 9 via bootable USB. Everything went well. But at the first boot after boot menu the error pops out:

> *ERROR* RADEON KERNEL MODESETTING FOR R600 OR LATER REQUIRES FIRMWARE-AND-GRAPHICS.

And after this, I don't even get to login screen, the screen just shuts down.

So I googled it and I know that this is a problem with my graphics card drivers. I tried to boot in recovery mode, however same situation. After pressing enter screen again goes black.

Thak you in advance

Answer (score 4):

Boot in [recovery mode with network](https://nology.de/debian-recovery-mode-turn-on-networking.html). You may need an additional boot parameter, `nomodeset` or `radeon.modeset=0`.

Then, enable the "non-free" repository. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and enable or add the following

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free contrib
```

Update the software sources and install firmware for AMD Graphics

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-amd-graphics
```

Reboot.

Comment: `nomodeset` works against blank screen on a HP Microserver Gen10 with AMD CPU/GPU

Comment: At the time of this reply, you would need to change "testing" to "stretch", since this is currently the stable version. The instructions at the URL for enabling networking did not work. These two commands did work: (1) systemctl enable NetworkManager.service, (2) systemctl start NetworkManager.service.

Comment: `nomodeset` didn't work for me. Following the [comments here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=72742), I started in recovery mode without extra boot parameters, and then after logging in and using the command `dhclient <adaptor name>`, my ethernet adapter was up. Find your ethernet adaptor name with `ip addr` (e.g. `enp8s0`).